# Graph API Service Principal

Tags: azure

When I create a service principal using graph API. I am unable to find it in my Azure Account.
Creating an App inside Azure automatically creates a Service principal inside

Comment: Could you add the code/script used?

Comment: Hey juunas. thanks for your reply. I found the solution. We need to pass 
 tags: [ 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp' ] along with appId while creating a servicePrincipal (for any app created via graph api) so that this service principal falls under category of enterprise application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Taslim Arif's comment, I posted it as an answer to end the thread:

> We need to pass tags: [ 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp' ]
> along with appId while creating a servicePrincipal (for any app
> created via graph api) so that this service principal falls under
> category of enterprise application.